# How to assert list of objects for Theory MemberData?

Tags: c#, xunit

I have this integration test code using Xunit in C#. My question is how do I assert for multiple objects with multiple results?

```
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(ClientIsEmptyOrNull_Data))]
    public async Task When_ClientIsEmptyOrNull_Then_ReturnErrorMessage(List<MarketingLeadDto> marketingLeadDtos, 
        List<string> expectedErrorMessages)
    {            
        using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(TestSettings.BaseAddress) })
        {
            _output.WriteLine("authToken: {0}", _authToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);

            foreach (var marketingLeadDto in marketingLeadDtos)
            {
                var encodedContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(marketingLeadDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await client.PostAsync("/ABC/Leads", encodedContent);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _output.WriteLine("response: {0}", responseString);

                HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, statusCode);

                //expectedErrorMessages.Should().BeEquivalentTo(marketingLeadDtos);
            }
            
        }
    }

    public static TheoryData<List<MarketingLeadDto>, List<string>> ClientIsEmptyOrNull_Data()
    {
        return new TheoryData<List<MarketingLeadDto>, List<string>>
        {
            {
                new List<MarketingLeadDto>
                {
                    new MarketingLeadDto
                        {
                            AccountType = "1",
                            Salutations = "1",
                            Name = "Steven",
                            CompanyName = "",
                            Nationality = "",
                            Client = "",
                        }
                },
                new List<string>
                {
                    "Client type is required"
                }                    
            }                
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using classic for loop. Not sure if there is a better way. For example, `FluentAssertions`.

```
            for (int x = 0; x < marketingLeadDtos.Count; x++)
            {                    
                var encodedContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(marketingLeadDtos[x]), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await client.PostAsync("/ABC/Leads"
                    , encodedContent);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _output.WriteLine("response: {0}", responseString);

                HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, statusCode);
                Assert.Equal(expectedErrorMessages[x], responseString);                    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had met with a similar issue before then and solved it with the below solution. Hopefully, it helps someones.

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(ClassName))]
public void TestYourMethod(YourRequest request)
{
    //Test Codes
}


public class ClassName: IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
         yield return new object[]
         {
             new YourRequest()
                  {
                     //Your properties
                  };
         };
         yield return new object[]
         {
             new YourRequest()
                  {
                     //Your properties
                  };
         };
     }
     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```